# custom segue transition from UIButton

Tags: ios, ios6, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have to 4 scene on my storyboard and everything works great, but right now I have a modal style with transition cover vertical. I want to have modal style but with a horizontal cover transition.

I change from scene to scene with a round rect button because my scenes does not have a navigation bar (because I don't need it).

I found a tutorial and I create a new class to override the perform method.

Here is my implementation file with the perfom method.

```
#import "JHCustomSegue.h"
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"

@implementation JHCustomSegue

- (void) perform {

    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = .25;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom



    [sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                                forKey:kCATransition];

    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];

}


@end
```

But the transition doesn't work I can chance to any of my scene I always stay in the first screen.

What I'm doing wrong, because the example works very well but they use a navigation bar.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you certain that the segue is firing? Put a log in the perform method and see what is happening. It might be just a matter of not having linked it correctly.

Comment: may be you are not using a navigation controller but you use `[sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                                forKey:kCATransition];

    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];`. You need to modify that part.